# Live chat won't open from any browser on Win7

Tags: livechat

After a window 7 update, live chat won't open from any browser.
Script works fine from other laptops and browser, but not from those with win7. The links open the livechatinc.com page, and in console I get:

```
LC_Invite is not defined
```

Comment: This might be a better question for superuser.com

Comment: This is completely off-topic. Have you tried spoofing your user-agent? Could be a buggy site. But yes, off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I went through some forums and found this maybe your the problem is that `LC_Invite` is still being loaded when `onChatLoaded` is called.